# jdk path for oracle java installation by ppa repository

Tags: java-8

I have installed oracle java on ubuntu via ppa repository. Now I want to extract the jdk path of the installation. I looked intto the following path as follows:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
```

But I do not see any jdk installed under this path. Once I type the command

```
javac -version
```

I do get the following:

```
javac 1.8.0_144
```

So it means that JDK is installed by PPA as well. I need some hint to locate the JDK path.

Answer (score 0):

Type `which java` on the command line and it will tell you where on the path it is finding the executable.

That file may itself be a symbolic link. You can `ls -l` the file to see where it is linked. You may then need to do so again if there are more levels of links. E.g.:

`paul@pcb ~ $ which java
/usr/bin/java
paul@pcb ~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Nov 16  2015 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
paul@pcb ~ $ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May 11 14:48 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
paul@pcb ~ $`